# Customize the ActionMenu of an EditText

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I want to provide simple formatting buttons for an `EditText`, for example, a button that inserts `<strong></strong>` if no text was selected and wraps the selected text in `<strong>` tags otherwise.

I am using the Support Library v7 with `ActionBarCompat`. I managed to start a custom `ActionMode` upon focus change of my `EditText`. However, when I long-touch on text in that `EditText`, another `ActionMode` menu opens with copy/paste/... buttons, which presumably is Android's default behaviour. How can I suppress this second menu, but still let the user select portions of the `EditText`'s content?

Alternatively I would like to be able to customize the default menu using `setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(...)` but using the Support library. How could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, `TextView` and `EditText` don't provide an API for you to use `ActionBarCompat` classes.  But, you should be able to override this behavior.

Set a custom `onLongClickListener` in which you set your own state information in your activity and call `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()`.  Be sure to return 'true' from your `OnLongClickListener.onLongClick()` method, indicating you consumed the click.  Then, in your `onPrepareOptionsMenu` you can add whatever new menu items you wish for your custom action bar.  I would recommend not using `TextView` context menu items IDs 'selectAll', 'cut', 'copy' and 'paste', just to be on the safe side.

Comment: Hi Larry, thank you for the answer. Of course I could implement my very own stuff, not to mention that I could just stop the EditText's ActionMenu from appearing. However, it seems as if text selection (with the dragable handles and so on) is kind of tightly coupled to that ActionMenu and would hence also be disabled. I could probably attempt to implement my own text selection behaviour, but that seems to be a lot of work and I really would like to avoid that... Any ideas on this?

Comment: Unfortunately, the core EditText (really it is the superclass TextView) manages this completely for you and sets its own action mode.  So if you disable the action mode and used your own action mode you would have to re-implement the select, copy, cut and paste operations.